# How to access IP address of HTTP requests using uWS?

Tags: c++, api, websocket, uwebsockets

I am using **uWebSockets** to do a project. What I need to do is get the sender IP address out of incoming HTTP Requests. In the documentation I can see IP address can be taken out from the **WebSockets**. Do anybody have an idea to **cast uWS to WebSockets** to get the data or is there an other way to get it?

```
#include <iostream>

#include "App.h"

int main() {

  /* Overly simple hello world app */

  uWS::App().get("/*", [](auto *res, auto *req) {

// **this is the place i need to access the ip address of the incoming HttpRequest**

    res->end("Hello world!");
  }).listen(3000, [](auto *listen_socket) {

    if (listen_socket) {
      std::cout << "Listening on port " << 3000 << std::endl;
    }
  }).

run();
  std::cout << "Failed to listen on port 3000" << std::endl;
}
```

Link of the library: https://unetworking.github.io/uWebSockets.js/generated/interfaces/WebSocketBehavior.html

Comment: the library is written in c++, And I am also using c++.(I am kind of a beginner)

Comment: Please edit your question with a representative sample of the application you have now and indicate the place where you need the sender IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://unetworking.github.io/uWebSockets.js/generated/interfaces/HttpResponse.html), the remote address is an attribute of the response. Ergo:

```
std::string_view remote_ip = res->getRemoteAddressAsText();
```

Comment: Marking a question as accepted will help others find this topic in the future.